# actions must be plain objects. use custom middleware for async actions, firebase, redux, redux-thunk

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux, react-redux

Error message line on ios virtual machine: actions must be plain objects. use custom middleware for async actions.
I noticed there was a problem at upLoadImageToFirebase().
I encountered this problem when using redux and firebase. Can someone help me? Many thanks!

```
"react-redux": "^6.0.1",
"redux": "^4.0.1",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
"react-native": "0.58.006",
```

```
upLoadImageToFirebase = (item) => {
    return storage.ref('imgProduct').child(`${item.key}.jpg`)
        .put(item.blob, { contentType: 'application/octet-stream' })
}

export const addProduct = (product) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        let { blobs } = product;
        let urls = [];
        dispatch(startAdd());
        blobs.forEach((item) => {
            dispatch(upLoadImageToFirebase(item)).then((snapshoot) => {
                urls = urls.concat(snapshoot.ref.getDownloadURL());
            }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your store setup? and the second dispatch should also dispatch something like `{ type: 'MY_ACTION_TYPE', payload: someData }`

Comment: Please post your `src/index.js` file and your `actions/index.js` file, unless you are telling me what you have above is your action creator, its unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are using redux-thunk. Check if you have added that in middleware also.

Comment: I added applyMiddleware (thunk) to the store in my project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your not returning a function. Your returning a promise. To fix this just change the `upLoadImageToFirebase` function to this:

```
upLoadImageToFirebase = (item) => {
    return () => {
        return storage.ref('imgProduct').child(`${item.key}.jpg`)
            .put(item.blob, { contentType: 'application/octet-stream' })
    }
}
```

You need to wrap the async promise in a function or thunk won't recognize it. Even if you don't need access to dispatch, it is still a necessary step.